# HttpSession setAttribute doesn't always insert new object

Tags: java, weblogic12c, httpsession

I am working on an upgrade from WLS10g and JavaEE6 to WLS12c and JavaEE7.

I have noticed a difference on how `HttpSession.setAttribute` works. In WLS10, any object already stored under a certain key would always be replaced.

In WLS12 the object is not replaced if `newObject.equals(oldObject)`.

This is a problem for us, because the applications have objects like this:

```
class ValueObject {
    int key;
    String data;

    @Override
    public int hashCode()
    {
      return key;
    }

    boolean equals(Object o) {
        if (o == null || (o instanceof ValueObject) == false) {
            return false;
        }
        ValueObject otherObject = (ValueObject)o;
        /* Return true if the keys are equal, even though the data may differ */
        return key == otherObject.key;
    }
}
```

The ValueObject gets modified through a workflow that spans several web pages. The intermediate values are stored in the `HTTPSession` and at the end of the workflow the modified value is written to the database.

In the servlets there is code like this (the members are actually modified through getters/setters, but I am simplifying to reduce the amount of code in the question):

```
public void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException {
    HttpSession session = request.getSession();
    ValueObject newValue = new ValueObject();
    newValue.key = Integer.parseInt(request.getParameter("key"));
    newValue.data = request.getParameter("data");
    session.setAttribute("value", newValue);
    ...
```

`newValue.key` is unmodified while `newValue.data` has a new value.

The modified behaviour of the `HttpSession` in WLS12 breaks this pattern - when the object is retrieved from the session we get the `data` from the first step since the object isn't replaced when we try to store updated versions.

We could solve this by changing all updates from:

```
session.setAttribute("value", newValue);
```

to

```
session.removeAttribute("value");
session.setAttribute("value", newValue);
```

However, there are more than 100 servlets so it is a lot of work. And the workaround is both ugly and prone to errors because the programmers need to keep track of one more thing when writing code.

Is there any way to configure WLS12c to use the old behaviour where the object always is replaced by `HttpSession.setAttribute()`?

**Update 2015-09-30**:

Bug report filed with Oracle. I've tried the filter idea suggested by wero. It seems Weblogic expects the object coming down the filter chain to be of class `weblogic.server.internal.ServletRequestImpl`, because when I wrapped it and sent the wrapper down the filter chain I got a ClassCastException from an internal Weblogic class.

I have also checked the configuration options as suggested by Gimby. I could not find any applicable option for the Session. We deploy to a single server and use `memory` as session persistence setting.

**Update 2016-02-03**:

Oracle has closed the bug report as "Not a bug".

Comment: Is there any reason why you can't simply correct the equals implementation?

Comment: There are maybe 50 different value objects and it is not immediately clear what other implications such a change would have. Some parts of the code relies on the equality to check that two different value objects refer to the same row in the database.

Comment: Hm, my gut tells me this happens due to session replication / serialization to minimize unnecessary updates. Might be worth investigating that corner of the configuration.

Comment: I am facing this error in Weblogic 12.1.3. It certainly appears to be a faulty Weblogic implementation. They seem to have closed the bug as 'Not a bug'.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since Oracle closed the bug report as "not a bug" I decided to implement the workaround.

I went through all calls to `HttpSession.setAttribute` and identified which calls used an object that potentially could trigger the bug.

In those places I replaced

```
session.setAttribute(key, newValue);
```

with

```
session.removeAttribute(key);
session.setAttribute(key, newValue);
```

along with a comment explaining why the extra line was needed.

Answer (score 2):

Not an answer to your question about a workaround, but the Javadoc of `Session.setAttribute` is very clear about the behaviour:

> Binds an object to this session, using the name specified. If an
>   object of the same name is already bound to the session, the object is
>   **replaced**.

So you could always file a bugreport.

A workaround could use a Filter to install a wrapped `HttpServletRequest` which returns a wrapped `HttpSession` which overrides `setAttribute` and implements the replace-then-set-logic.

Comment: I have filed a bugreport and also tried the wrapper idea. Unfortunately the wrapper idea failed - Weblogic tries to cast the HttpSession to the internal class `weblogic.server.internal.ServletRequestImpl`. The cast fails miserably when I send the wrapper object down the filter chain.